# How to delete a JSON Array value in JSON Object

Tags: java, json

I have a JSON object as shown bellow.I would like to delete the value of the JSON array in the JSON Object using java.I tried using javascript and did it but I am confused with Java.

```
{
    "aaa":"0px",
    "bbb":"sadsda",
    "ccc":
    {
        "ddd":
        {
            "eee":"initial","dsa":"none","asd":"none","caption":"","type":"image","title":"test.txt","align":"center","resolution":null,"captionMargin":"0px auto","href":"ttt/bbb.zzz?cfr=148c273959c9&od=1572cfa","componentbottombordersize":"none","height":null,"border":"0","padding":1,"das":"","src":"ooo","alt":"test.txt","componentbgcolor":"transparent","yandex":null,"target":"_self","hhhh":"none","size":"F","google":"none","microsoft":"100%","name":""
        },
        "freshdesk":
        {
            "oooo"
        }
    },
    "width":600,
    "zarket":
    {
        "array":["value1","value2"]
    },
    "type":"mailchimp",
    "height":251
}
```

I want to delete `value1` of `array`.How Can I do it using java?

Comment: Do you use a library like jackson, gson or so?

Comment: Yes we use GSON

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - nice to have you. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help keeping Stack Overflows content on the highest possible level and increase your chances getting an appropriate answer. Please provide the code that you are using currently and then we could help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Include this in maven
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson

Try this

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
YourJsonObject yourObj = gson.fromJson(reader, YourJsonObject.class);
if(yourObj.getZarket()!=null && yourObj.getZarket().getArray()!=null){
    yourObj.getZarket().getArray().remove("value1");
}
```

// Assuming you will create a class YourJsonObject with the above attributes of json and the array attribute will be a list. if its an array, remove by searching the value in an array using iterations